# does chrome still have issue with not deleting session cookie?

Tags: google-chrome, session-cookies

I've read a lot of topics about Chrome not deleting session cookie when the browser is closed, but most of them are dated year ago or earlier. Currenly I'm experiencing the same problem with Chrome of the versioh `33.0.1750.154 m`. Is this problem not yet fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes chrome still has this problem and Ive seen it in the latest IE as well. Ive been doing alot of testing with an application that has session based cookies and I see that value even when I completely close all chrome windows.  What works for me is either to use Firefox or to use Chrome Incognito window.  You have to close all chrome windows still when using Incognito

Comment: Thanks, but the solutions you offered don't solve the problem since I I can't expect users of my application to follow them. Is there any work-around for the issue that an application developer can do to enforce deletion?